# Can't use drop down menus of Mulestudio on Ubuntu13.10

Tags: mule-studio, ubuntu-13.10

I just newly upgraded my `ubuntu` to 13.10, and I found the menus of `Mule Studio` (64-bit linux) upon the unity bar freezing up, i.e. can't open any menu from there.

Has anyone else come across the same issue? And is there a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by a bug in Ubuntu affecting both eclipse and studio. I was able to work around it by following the steps available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/saucy-upgrade-causes-menu-problem-in-eclipse)

Comment: tyvm for sharing the link, it's beautiful

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with any Name. Example. Mule

Add the following line in to the file

> Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /opt/MuleStudio/MuleStudio

Make sure the path **/opt/MuleStudio/MuleStudio** is your MuleStudio executable path
Save the file and Exit

Got to command prompt and execute the below like to give executable permission to the file.

```
   ~$ cd [your file path]

   ~$ chmod 777 Mule
```

and then execute the file using the below command,

```
   ~$ ./Mule
```

Now you can get your Menu in your Mule studio...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Santiagu, I went to ElementaryOS after this issue but definitely will try it in my other VMs.